# models.pyの中で、複数のクラスの効率的な作り方

Tags: python, python3, django

python3,Djangoでwebシステムを開発しています。

その中で、同じ項目のmodelのクラスを複数作る必要があり、効率的な方法を考えております。
良い方法がありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか？

例えば）下記のような都道府県の情報のクラスを作るようなケースです。
都道府県の数クラスを作りますが、各クラスの違いはクラスの名前だけです。
作成後に、makemigrations, migrateを行います。

```
class Hokkaido(models.Model):
    namae = models.CharField('namae', max_length=10)
    zinkou = models.CharField('zinkou', max_length=10)
    menseki = models.IntegerField('menseki')


    def __str__(self):
        return (self.namae)


class Akita(models.Model):
    namae = models.CharField('namae', max_length=10)
    zinkou = models.CharField('zinkou', max_length=10)
    menseki = models.IntegerField('menseki')


    def __str__(self):
        return (self.namae)

#このようなクラスが、都道府県数つくられる。
```

for分を使った方法が、ぱっと思い浮かびます。
例えば）下記のようなケース

```
todohuken = ['Hokkaido', 'Akita', 'Iwate']

for i in range(len(todohuken)):

    class todohuken[i](models.Model):#←class名を配列を使って指定したい
        namae = models.CharField('namae', max_length=10)
        zinkou = models.CharField('zinkou', max_length=10)
        menseki = models.IntegerField('menseki')

        def __str__(self):
            return (self.namae)
```

この場合だと、エラーが出てしまいます。

---

【コメントをいただいた後の追記】

質問時に載せたコードは、質問用としてサンプルで作成しました。
下記のコードが実際に使用する予定もモデルのクラスの内容です（。
各クラスの内容は、CSVよりデータをインポートして作成します。

```
class HokkaidoSapporo(models.Model):

    pref_no = models.PositiveIntegerField('pref_no', default=1)
    block_no = models.PositiveIntegerField('block_no', default=101)

    date = models.DateField('date')
    ave_temp = models.FloatField('ave_temp')
    max_temp = models.FloatField('max_temp')
    min_temp = models.FloatField('min_temp')
    rain = models.PositiveIntegerField('rain')
    sun = models.FloatField('sun')
    weather = models.CharField('weather', max_length=10)

class HokkaidoAsahikawa(models.Model):

    pref_no = models.PositiveIntegerField('pref_no', default=1)
    block_no = models.PositiveIntegerField('block_no', default=102)

    date = models.DateField('date')
    ave_temp = models.FloatField('ave_temp')
    max_temp = models.FloatField('max_temp')
    min_temp = models.FloatField('min_temp')
    rain = models.PositiveIntegerField('rain')
    sun = models.FloatField('sun')
    weather = models.CharField('weather', max_length=10)
```

このような場合、外部キーを利用して、以下のような内容に変更するのが得策でしょうか？

```
class PrefNo(models.Model):
    pref_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('pref_id')
    pref_no = models.PositiveIntegerField('pref_no')


class BlockNo(models.Model):
    block_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('block_id')
    block_no = models.PositiveIntegerField('block_no')


class Wheather(models.Model):
    pref_no = models.ForeignKey(PrefNo, 'pref_no', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    block_no = models.ForeignKey(BlockNo, 'block_no', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    weather_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('weather_id')
    date = models.DateField('date')
    ave_temp = models.FloatField('ave_temp')
    max_temp = models.FloatField('max_temp')
    min_temp = models.FloatField('min_temp')
    rain = models.PositiveIntegerField('rain')
    sun = models.FloatField('sun')
    weather = models.CharField('weather', max_length=10)
```

この考えで正しい場合、都道府県（それぞれの地域含む）の数だけ、テーブルを作る時はどのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？

テーブルを作成してから、[管理者画面より、CSVデータを利用して、各都道府県（それぞれの地域含む）にデータを保存させる作業を行います](https://blog.daisukekonishi.com/post/django-import-export-csv/)。

そのため、コードを動かしてテーブルを作るのではなく、makemigratins,migrateを行って、あらかじめテーブルを作成する必要があります。

Comment: そもそもそうした個々の都道府県名のクラスを作ることが非効率では？ 都道府県名は既にデータに含まれているようなので、クラス名を`todohuken`とか`prefecture`にすれば良いのでは？ [Python/Django アプリでよく使うコード【都道府県】](https://qiita.com/Liverty/items/b60278eaed3e84c20b8b), [【Python】【Django】お天気予報機能1(要件整理)](https://qiita.com/oshiro-pooh/items/4c48e3ca7a39e4f137bf), [GeoDjangoでWeb地図をつくろう！](https://medium.com/infradatachallenge/idc-river-ce0f6cd3da43)

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。外部キーを利用して複数のテーブルに対応するという事でしょうか？なお、makemigrations,migrateにて、あらかじめテーブルを作成する必要もありまして、その方法等もあれば教えていただけないでしょうか？詳細は質問欄に追記させていただきました。

Comment: 紹介した記事の続きとかが参考になるのでは？ [【Python】【Django】お天気予報機能2(xmlから取得したデータをDBに登録)](https://qiita.com/oshiro-pooh/items/2071b38cbe02807c086f) データファイルを csvやxmlで用意して登録するとか。目的や方法が違いますが、他にこんな記事も参考になるかも。[DJANGO環境で郵便番号⇒住所自動入力（YubinBango api）](https://qiita.com/kk-ster/items/4618dd0a499c2c405b47), [Django + django-localflavorで、フォームの郵便番号入力や都道府県選択を作成してみた](https://thinkami.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/08/082156), [都道府県と市区町村を紐付けて表示したい](https://teratail.com/questions/69695)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。今回、私が使用するシステムでは、pref_no,block_noの一覧は自分で作成するため、お天気予報機能2の内容を参考にして、CSVを元にテーブルを作成するのが適しているかと思います。今回の情報を参考させていただき、また開発を行おうと思います。ありがとうございます。